# Change Value of Excel Cell when another cell contains specific character

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I created a multi-sheet Excel workbook to track workouts. Page 1 is a calendar with clickable links to each other page. Each other page is a specific type of workout. So if you click today's date on the calendar, it will take you to the page for the workout you are supposed to do today.

On each of the workout pages, there is a field called "Completed". My goal is to change a text cell next to today's date cell on Page 1 to an "x" when I type an "x" in the "completed" cell on that workout's page. So basically, if Page 2's "Completed" cell (let's say it is cell C21) has an "x" in it, then the cell next to today's date on Page 1 (let's say it is cell D3) will change its value from the date to a simple "x".

Does anyone have any pointers on how I can accomplish this? Here is the spreadsheet: http://www.sendspace.com/file/ci7str

To be clear, if I mark the very first workout "completed", I'd like the "1" in cell D3 to change from "1" to "x".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set one of these up for each sheet on sheet 1-

`Sheet1!D3 = if(Sheet2!C21="x","x","1")`